# Pandas stats plain table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of statistical foreign trade data stacked up in a single table/csv:
year, is_export (otherwise it's import), country, customs code, macro code (a group of customs codes) and value (in dollars).

I would love to be able to use pandas to group the data (instead of using plain sql) and get something like:

```
macro_group=12

2012  2013 2014
country
export
```

Do I just have to do several `groupby` calls (on the "keys" I want to build a hierarchy upon)?

Edit: all the rows are identical:

```
id|Country|Year|Export|Macro|Code|Codename|Value
1|China|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|0.0
2|Germany|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|59.9
3|Italy|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|33.2
```

What I would like to get is:

```
**Macro e.g. 23**
China total export
2012 2013 2014
432  34  3243

China total import
2012 2013 2014
4534 345  4354

Russia total import...
```

etc

Comment: Some minimal test data to play with would be helpful ;)

Comment: Your desired output doesn't really tell me much can you explain what it's showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no entirely clear what your expected output is (given the data you provided). I guess that you want the total values per country and year (if not, feel free to correct me):

```
import pandas as pd

########### Setup some test data: #############
s = """id|Country|Year|Export|Macro|Code|Codename|Value
1|China|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|0.0
2|Germany|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|59.9
3|Germany|2013|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|80.0
4|Germany|2013|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|40.0
5|Italy|2012|1|69|6996700|Articles,of iron or steel wire,n.e.s.|33.2"""

from StringIO import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|')

pd.Series.__unicode__ = pd.Series.to_string # suppress meta-data when printing

########### The real stuff happens here: #############
macro = 69
group_by = df[df.Macro == macro].groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['Value'].sum()

for country in df.Country.unique():   
    print '---', country, '---'
    print group_by[country]
    print
```

Which results in the following output:

```
--- China ---
2012    0

--- Germany ---
2012     59.9
2013    120.0

--- Italy ---
2012    33.2
```